# Oracle SQL Developer how to see output of a sp

Tags: sql, oracle

I have done right click on the SP and the right side has an embedded table that has the params but I can't seem to enter the params there. I was able to do what I needed in PL SQL but how do I run SP's now?

Answer (score 0):

you can run via block of plsql code.

if you want to run only you can use following types of block--

```
declare
/*
parameter declaration .. just like your parameter types in SP.
like ..
*/
l_p_input_1 varchar2(980):= '<value you want to give>';
l_p_input_2 number := 33;
l_p_output_1 varchar2(889);
begin

sp_your_sP_name(l_p_input_1,
                l_p_input_2,
                l_p_output_1);
dbms_output.put_line('l_p_output_1 : '||l_p_output_1);
end;
```